# ¿Por qué siempre cambia el orden de una matriz asociativa en Perl?

Tags: perl, matrices-asociativas, ordenamiento

Tengo esta matriz asociativa en un pequeño programa de Perl que hace algo muy raro:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:utf8 :std);

my %distancia = (
    esto    =>   1,
    eso     =>  10,
    aquello => 100,
    aquí    =>   1,
    ahí    =>   10,
    allí    => 100,
);

for my $clave (keys %distancia) {
    my $valor = $distancia{$clave};
    printf "%-8s es %3d.\n", $clave, $valor;
}
```

Cada vez que la imprimo, cambia el orden al azar:

```
mac(tchrist)% perl matriz-asociativa
esto     es   1.
aquello  es 100.
eso      es  10.
allí     es 100.
ahí      es  10.
aquí     es   1.

mac(tchrist)% perl matriz-asociativa
eso      es  10.
ahí      es  10.
aquí     es   1.
esto     es   1.
aquello  es 100.
allí     es 100.

mac(tchrist)% perl matriz-asociativa
allí     es 100.
aquí     es   1.
ahí      es  10.
eso      es  10.
esto     es   1.
aquello  es 100.

mac(tchrist)% perl matriz-asociativa
aquello  es 100.
aquí     es   1.
allí     es 100.
esto     es   1.
eso      es  10.
ahí      es  10.

mac(tchrist)% perl matriz-asociativa
ahí      es  10.
aquí     es   1.
eso      es  10.
aquello  es 100.
allí     es 100.
esto     es   1.
```

¿Qué me está pasando aquí, y qué debo hacer para obtener un orden determinado cada vez?

Si importa, dice que la versión de perl que tengo es la **v5.22.0**:

```
mac(tchrist)% perl -v

This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 (v5.22.0) built for darwin-2level

Copyright 1987-2015, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Una tabla hash es una estructura de datos con la que se pretende conseguir un acceso rápido a unos datos, a partir de una clave.

Existe una serie de ataques, conocidos como ataques de complejidad algorítmica, que consisten en hacer que una parte del código de un programa empiece a funcionar en un régimen de rendimiento pésimo. Con esto, se puede conseguir realizar una denegación de servicio (DoS, por sus siglas en inglés), y privar al resto de usuarios de un servicio de acceso a ese servicio.

Para evitar estos ataques, se utilizan una serie de medidas, como añadir una entrada aleatoria a la función hash utilizada. Como efecto secundario, esto causa que el orden de claves de la función hash sea no determinista.

Para conseguir un orden determinista, bastaría con ordenar las claves:

```
for my $clave (sort keys %distancia) {
    my $valor = $distancia{$clave};
    printf "%-8s es %3d.\n", $clave, $valor;
}
```

Por supuesto, si quieres un orden alfabético de verdad, tendrás que usar un algoritmo de ordenación alfabética, como UCA, que en Perl está disponible como `Unicode::Collate::Locale`.

Comment: Me allegro de ver que mencionaste el UCA, pues de otro modo los textos castellanos no siempre salen bien.

Answer (score 11):

Hay un error en lo que escribes: Cambia el orden cada vez que ejecutas el programa, no cada vez que imprimes el array asociativo.

El array asociativo en realidad no es un array asociativo, sino una [Tabla Hash](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_hash). El orden esta dado por el hash que utiliza como indice, por eso en cada ejecución el orden es totalmente distinto.

Si imprimes en un mismo programa, dos veces la misma tabla hash, vas a ver que su orden no es alterado.

El orden de una tabla hash también puede ser alterado en el caso de que se agreguen o quiten elementos, ya que si llega a haber colisiones la tabla tiene que modificarse.

Entonces, en un programa siempre vas a tener el hash ordenado de la misma forma.

Si quieres obtener el hash ordenado siempre, tendrás que ordenarlo tú de alguna forma.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente código ordena alfabéticamente las claves, y las muestra por pantalla.

```
foreach my $name (sort {lc $a cmp lc $b} keys %distancia) {
    printf "%-8s %s\n", $name, $distancia{$name};
}
```

*Edit*

Desde Perl 5.8, a la funcion hash utilizada para obtener el hash de cada par clave-valor insertado, se le agrego una semilla aleatoria por cuestiones de seguridad (para evitar [ataques de complejidad algoritmica]).

Comment: Esta respuesta no explica por qué el orden *cambia* en cada ejecución, únicamente explica por qué es arbitrario.

Comment: No me parecio relevante la verdad. Pero ahi lo agrego.